# Declaring input port arrays in single statement vs. multiple statements

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

My teacher told me that its good practice to declare packed input arrays in different statements rather than in one. For example:

```
input [3:0] a,b;   //create two inputs ports of 4 bits
```

vs.

```
input [3:0] a;    //create one port "a" of 4 bits           
input [3:0] b;    //create one port "b" of 4 bits
```

The teacher has told me the second style is more preferable; however, both work the same. Is there any reason for the second style of declaration? Does it help in synthesis or prevent errors while instantiating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second style is preferred because relying on all Verilog's implicit declaration rules leaves lots of room for mistakes. By putting each port on one line the intent is explicitly shown. Also, the ANSI style of port declarations is preferred so that each port name is listed only once

Fully explicit ANSI style from Verilog-2001 (`wire logic` would be implicit if left out)

```
module mod(
  input wire logic [3:0] a,    //create one input port "a" of 4 bits           
  input wire logic [3:0] b,    //create one input port "b" of 4 bits
  output var logic [3:0] c    //create one output port "c" of 4 bits
);
```

Non-ANSI style from Verilog-1995

```
module mod(a, b, c);
  input [3:0] a;    //create one input port "a" of 4 bits           
  input [3:0] b;    //create one input port "b" of 4 bits
  output [3:0] c;   //create one output port "c" of 4 bits
  logic [3:0] c; // port c listed 3 times
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference between the two coding styles.  They will both simulate the same way, and they will both synthesize the same way.  The second style does not help in synthesis or prevent errors while instantiating.

You should ask your teacher for the reason for this preference.  Without a reason, it is purely a matter of opinion.

Perhaps the teacher thinks it is easier to read and understand code if there is one signal declaration per line.